# Git/Github not seeing changes in repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

When another team member makes a change to a project in Visual Studio C# 2019 I can't see the change.

Steps:

1. I create a project, clicked Add to Source Control/Git then Publish to GitHub.
2. Another team member cloned the project, made a change, and pushed the changed to GitHub. I was logged into GitHub and could see the change that was uploaded.
3. I went to Team Explorer/Home and hit Sync and it said there no Incoming Commits???
4. I was able to get the latest version from GitHub by deleting my local project and cloning the latest version, so I know the latest version was on GitHub

Comment: Does it work if you use `git pull` in the command line, rather than click "Sync"?